# Easier way to unpack data of a .blend file with php?

Tags: php, endianness, blender, unpack

Currently I want to read some data (metadata, scene names, mesh count, vertices count ...) from a `.blend` file with the `unpack()` function of PHP refering to the `Blender SDNA` documentation:

http://www.atmind.nl/blender/blender-sdna-256.html

Is there some easy solution to read all these information with some existing classes or libraries or do I have to read block by block from the file and write my own functions / clas / library (so I can create something like an object)?

Comment: I'm afraid you do. I'll try to check something for you but I'm more skeptical than positive.

Comment: it seems like there is nothing, you should write your own :(

Comment: you could share the class though if you do manage to achieve this!

Comment: Thanks. I will start soon with a serverside / php version and also a javascript version just for blender / .blend and x3d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After consultation with php manual I can tell you that php just doesn't provide way to read binary files, but I think there's quite nice way to do this (inspirited by [c and fread](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/94493))

```php
class BinaryReader {
    const FLOAT_SIZE = 4;

    protected $fp = null; // file pointer
    ...

    public function readFloat() {
         $data = fread( $fp, self::FLOAT_SIZE);
         $array = unpack( 'f', $data);
         return $array[0];
    }

     // Reading unsigned short int
     public function readUint16( $endian = null){
          if( $endian === null){
               $endian = $this->getDefaultEndian();
          }

          // Assuming _fread handles EOF and similar things
          $data = $this->_fread( 2);
          $array = unapack( ($endian == BIG_ENDIAN ? 'n' : 'v'), $data);
          return $array[0];
     }

    // ... All other binary type functions

    // You may also write it more general:
    public function readByReference( &$variable){
        switch( get_type( $variable)){
            case 'double':
                return $this->readDouble();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any improvements or tips, just post them in the comment I'll be glad to extend the answer.

Comment: fread and file_get_contents read binary file as i know? also its endian and not float =)

Comment: @DanielRuf file_get_contents should be binary safe too, but when you're opening 2,5,20,... MB large model and you need to parse only certain headers, you would want to do it like: `read number of chunks; go to first chunk; get its size; get count of mashes; skip it and read next chunk;` instead of loading whole file. And I don't understand the second part of comment, do you have problem with endians?

Comment: the models are not so big =) also it depends on the server settings and server hardware  i know and thats what you can do also with fread   you have double in your script and float but that is not endian, the unpack statement for little and big endian is other

Comment: @DanielRuf I'm quite enthusiastic about this one. I've added `readUint16` method so it'll be clean what I have it mind (this includes handling of different endians example). I know that this example is missing function at least for 32 and 64bit types, chars and correct handling for double/float. But it was meant as an example how to solve your problem. I believe it does. If it doesn't give me an example what you need to do what you can't with this method.

Comment: i tjink you misunderstood the blender sdna   the whole file is endian so it is unpack(v or V)   I mean a way to create an object directly from the file (but there are different blocks, data with different size and length ...)